# android : ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED not received (xperia SO-03D)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-install-apk, sony-xperia

When a new application is installed , my BroadcastReceiver gets package data with a simple filter :

```
filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);
filter.addDataScheme("package");

receiver = new newPackageReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

...

public class newPackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final String info = intent.getData().toString();
            ...
            }
    }
```

BroadcastReceiver is called with most of devices... However, with this [device](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-03D) (only in japanese, sorry), onReceive is never called.

- model: sony SO-03D
- android-version: 4.0.4

No update available for the device.... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps.
Try to add the receiver to the manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in YourReceiver class:

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String act = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED.equals(act) || Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.equals(act)) {
            //Do what you want
        }
}
```

I hope this would help, but it seems that the problem is with this device's rom.